# Does Flickr have support for private URLs?

Tags: permissions, flickr

[Picasa Web Albums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picasa#Picasa_Web_Albums) lets me give out a private URL to view an album. Is a similar feature available in [Flickr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flickr)?

I know I can adjust permissions based on the contact level, but I'd like to give semi-private access to people without requiring them to register.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using a `Guest Pass`, take a look [here](https://help.flickr.com/en_us/create-or-delete-temporary-guest-passes-in-flickr-Bygpmj1Q).